# Can't find fcitx button on the top of the screen ---Ubuntu17.10

Tags: input-method, fcitx

After updated ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 I installed fcitx to obtain Chinese Input method. But the strange thing is that I can no longer find fcitx icon where i can switch my input method and setup them on the top of the screen near the wifi signal.
But there is one thing need to mention, which is that I saw fcitx icon once when I just logged in the system, but it disappeared very soon like few seconds.
Now I don't know how to find it, Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think it will reappear if you relaunch Fcitx again.

With that said, I have not been able to use Fcitx in a convenient way on GNOME shell. GNOME is designed for IBus, and if you don't have a strong preference for Fcitx, I'd recommend you to use IBus instead.

Otherwise, if Fcitx is important to you, you may want to log in to a Unity session, or maybe try one of the Ubuntu flavors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case fcitx can work well with sogoupinyin if following packages are installed:

> fcitx-module-kimpanel fcitx-module-x11 fcitx-ui-classic gnome-shell-extension-appindicator

and make sure necessary add-ons are enabled in fcitx-config-gtk3 including:

> Kimpanel, x11 support

Re-login to enable the appindicator, then you should see an extra keyboard icon appearing on the top-right panel, which turns to the sogou icon when IM switched to sogoupinyin.